# How to change php version in WHM

Tags: shared-hosting, whm

I have a shared hosting(WHM), Let I have create 3 different hostname like

1)abc.com
2)xyc.com
3)hello.com

Now all three have same version of php. I want to change the php version of abc.com and xyz.com. Is it possible to change the version because it is shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You Can change php version for each site individually, in WHM control panel at software category select MultiPHP Manager and choose any site you like to change php version for

**Note :** Make sure you already have multi php version installed by easyapache V4

For more reference : https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/MultiPHP+Manager+for+WHM#PHPVersion

Comment: Just to add to this answer, if you don't see the 'multi php version' option make sure you're using the 'paper_lantern' theme, it doesn't show on the older 'x3' theme.

Answer (score 0):

On a shared hosting, you could try modifying `.htaccess` files to specify the PHP version that you want to use. On a dedicated server, you can follow these steps:

1. Login and search for "multiphp". Then click "MultiPHP Manager".

[image]

2. From the following screen, scroll all the way down:

[image]

[image]

3. From the "PHP Version" column of the previous image, select the PHP version that you want to use for each domain. You do not need to click anything. Simply select the PHP version that you want and as soon as you change your selection, the system will save the changes and you will have the new PHP version up and running for your domain.